# Hive Multi Select

Tags: sql, hive

```
CID    F_ID       NME
1       A          QR
1       B          QB
2       A          QR
3       B          QB
4       A          QR
4       B          QB
```

Result: -

```
CID F_ID    NME
1    A      QR
1    B      QB
4    A      QR
4    B      QB
```

In Hive, what's the query to get the result should only outcome the CID
that fall in both F_ID - A & B, I can acheive the same using LISTAGG in oracle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query will execute in single map-reduce stage:

```
select CID,    F_ID,       NME  from
(
select s.*, 
       sum(A) over (partition by CID) A_cnt,
       sum(B) over (partition by CID) B_cnt
from
(
select s.*,
       case when F_ID='A' then 1 else 0 end A,
       case when F_ID='B' then 1 else 0 end B
 from your_table
)s
)s where A_cnt>=1 and B_cnt >=1
;
```

Demo:

```
select CID,    F_ID,       NME  from
(
select s.*, 
       sum(A) over (partition by CID) A_cnt,
       sum(B) over (partition by CID) B_cnt
from
(
select s.*,
       case when F_ID='A' then 1 else 0 end A,
       case when F_ID='B' then 1 else 0 end B
 from
( --replace this subquery (s) with your table  
  select stack(6,
  1,       'A',          'QR',
  1,       'B',          'QB',
  2,       'A',          'QR',
  3,       'B',          'QB',
  4,       'A',          'QR',
  4,       'B',          'QB') as (CID,    F_ID,       NME)
) s
)s
)s where A_cnt>=1 and B_cnt >=1
;
```

Result:

```
MapReduce Jobs Launched:
Stage-Stage-1: Map: 1  Reduce: 1   Cumulative CPU: 6.39 sec   HDFS Read: 13549 HDFS Write: 28 SUCCESS
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 6 seconds 390 msec
OK
1       B       QB
1       A       QR
4       B       QB
4       A       QR
Time taken: 108.779 seconds, Fetched: 4 row(s)
```

Comment: Thanks leftjoin for the response and it's very useful, can you please let me know the performance improvement if the same query is executed in Impala

Comment: @kalis, I cannot help you with Impala performance improvement, sorry, because I do not use Impala, working on AWS platform. Ask this question with execution logs, etc, someone from the community will for sure help you with this.